# Testing Shake events on Android Emulator

Tags: android

Can any one help with how to test sensor events like shake on Android Emulator.
I have found some posts pointing to openintents but can anyone explain how to use it in android 2.0 avd

http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

This has some solution but while installing OpenIntents.apk on emulator gives missing library error.

I succeded the steps till the line:

> If you don't have it already, install
>   the latest version of OpenIntents.apk
>   on your mobile phone.

I am stuck on this line:

I found deprecated version (not latest) of OpenIntents.apk , but while installing gives missing library error.

Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How can I unit test an Android Activity that acts on Accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806976/how-can-i-unit-test-an-android-activity-that-acts-on-accelerometer/2807245#2807245) for a better solution.