# How can i simulate accelerometer in android emulator?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-virtual-device

I don't have an Android phone right now.  But in my application I need to use the accelerometer values.  How can I do this in a simulated environment?

Answer (score 38):

The Android emulator doesn't support it itself but OpenIntents' [SensorSimulator](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/openintents/sensorsimulator-2.0-rc1.zip) fills the void. Download and unpack the zip file, then start the standalone jar file:

```
$ java -jar bin/sensorsimulator.jar
```

Next, install SensorSimulatorSettings on the emulator using the adb tool which comes with the SDK:

```
$ adb -s <emulator device> install bin/SensorSimulatorSettings.apk
```

(run *adb devices* to find the emulator device name). Finally, run the installed SensorSimulatorSettings app in the emulator and enter the IP address **10.0.2.2** (despite what the SensorSimulator application might suggest. This is an alias to the loopback device of the development host so should always be valid.

Comment: I did all that, and when I try to control my simulator's accelerometer with SensorSimulator, nothing happens.

Comment: working link to download the zip file [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/openintents/sensorsimulator-2.0-rc1.zip), but because its been years since last commit, I wouldn't recommend trying this

Answer (score 20):

The recent version of emulator comes enabled with Accelerometer and other sensor simulation support. One can `telnet localhost 5554`:

> Trying 127.0.0.1...
>   Connected to localhost.
>   Escape character is '^]'.
>   Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
>   OK
>
> sensor
>   allows you to request the emulator sensors
>
> available sub-commands:
>      status           list all sensors and their status.
>      get              get sensor values
>      set              set sensor values
>
> KO: missing sub-command
>
> sensor status
>   acceleration: enabled.
>   magnetic-field: enabled.
>   orientation: enabled.
>   temperature: enabled.
>   proximity: enabled.
>   OK

How exactly to simulate a shake, I don't know. Try sending these two commands one after the other rapidly:

```
sensor set acceleration 0:0:0
sensor set acceleration 99:99:99
```

Comment: can "adb shell dumpsys sensorservice <>" use for simulation ?

Answer (score 6):

I also was trying to get the SensorSimulator working and I think I finally got it working.

The above steps:
"...java -jar bin/sensorsimulator.jar

Next, install SensorSimulatorSettings on the emulator using the adb tool which comes with the SDK:
$ adb -s  install bin/SensorSimulatorSettings.apk

...Finally, run the installed SensorSimulatorSettings app in the emulator and enter the IP address 10.0.2.2..."

are a good start, but I needed to do more.

You apparently need to then modify your application to use the SensorSimulator.  You can go to http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator and scroll down to the "How to use the SensorSimulator in your application" section.

Even then I got some errors in compiling, so you might want to see this page: [Vintage Thermometer component + SensorSimulator on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099084/vintage-thermometer-custom-ui-component-sensorsimulator-steps-to-test-the-com) - I had to remove the references to android.hardware.Sensor, SensorEvent, and SensorEventListener.

And then it was failing at the call to connectSimulator.  Apparently, I needed to give my application permission to use the Internet in the manifest file.

After all that, I am able to use the SensorSimulator to virtually rotate my phone and I do get the corresponding sensor readings in my application.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced that emulator for target 10 doesn't support accelerometer but for target 15 it does. I dont know if there is a way to do it for target 10.
So for testing your application, Create your project and AVD for target 15.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Genymotion application, it integrate a complete tool for the test of accelerometer and use a faster emulator: [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com)