# How do I simulate rotating the device with Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am running Android via the SDK emulator on Ubuntu. When you rotate some devices, they reset the layout to match (from portrait to landscape, or landscape to portrait). How can I simulate this on the emulator?

(Is this the same as [simulating the accelerometer, for example with OpenIntents' SensorSimulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921467/how-can-i-simulate-accelerometer-in-android-emulator), or is there more to it?)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can  use KEYPAD_7, Ctrl-F11 ,KEYPAD_9 or Ctrl-F12 to move to the next orientation

Comment: thanks nandeesh! is this referenced in the android documentation? if so could you provide a link? finally, these keys seem to rotate the phone between two orientations only (left-side down, bottom down), is this correct? (I can't turn it right-down or upside down)

Comment: you can check here. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html . If you repeatedly press KEYPAD_9 then it will rotate upside down i guess.

Comment: Seems outdated (?)

Answer (score 5):

I think, what you need is:

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> are your friends

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question has changed in 2023. Under the "Pixel 3 API 28" emulator running on Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1, there's a whole series of Extended Controls for simulating sensor inputs.

You can control the 3d orientation of the simulated device by opening the Extended Controls dialog with the 3 dots vertical menu in the Android emulator pane. That pops up a window; choose "Virtual sensors", then the "Device Pose" tab. It contains sliders to rotate the device in 3 axes.

Here's a screenshot of it in action while running a bubble/spirit level app.

[image: screenshot of the Extended Controls tool]