# How can i run a accelerometer code in emulator? Virtual device cant be titled to verify the code

Tags: android-emulator, accelerometer

Virtual device cant be titled to verify the code.
Then how can i verify code without tilting emulator

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921467/how-can-i-simulate-accelerometer-in-android-emulator

Comment: No this question is different. i wanna check the tilt effect

Comment: Can you please share little bit more detail on if its Native app or HTML5?