# Android Simulator: Telnet does not show the Sensor feature in my Android Studio version (2.2.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, telnet, android-sensors

as in object, I'm trying to solve the following problem. I was studying Android Emulator's features and I was looking for (as some online forums propose, for example here: [How can i simulate accelerometer in android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921467/how-can-i-simulate-accelerometer-in-android-emulator/20361772#20361772)) a way to communicate with the emulator console through Telnet. My host works on Android Studio version 2.2.1.

After the client Telnet was invoked (by using "telnet localhost 5554") and after authentication (using the key found in .emulator_console_auth_token), after I digited the "help" command, I didn't find the "sensor" in the command list shown. Everywhere on the Internet, is shown a situation in which sensor command is used to manage accelerometer, magnetometer, ecc..

Is it possible that from telnet it was removed the ability to set the sensor data? Do you have any advice about that?

thanks in advance

This is a screenshot of my situation with Telnet: 
[Help command results - Sensor command missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAX7p.jpg)

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, were you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in the latest release of sdk tools (25.3.1). The update can be installed by checking for updates in the latest version of Android Studio.

<strike>This seems to be an open issue tracked in [AOSP](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207176). The issue poster has mentioned that downgrading to Android Studio 1.5 fixes the issue.</strike>