# How to "shake" in Bluestacks?

Tags: bluestacks

One of my apps needs to use the motion sensor in my Android "cell phone".

Of course, I can't shake my computer by using BlueStacks.

I wonder how I can achieve the "shake" function in BlueStacks environment?

I tried left-right arrows, but it does not seem to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BlueStacks 2, it's supported. I don't think it's possible to really shake in BS1, but with BS2, you have the button in the sidebar.

[image: BlueStacks shake button]

[And you have also shortcuts](http://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/206467936-BlueStacks-2-Side-Toolbar)

Answer (score 1):

The shake feature in BlueStacks only shakes the device horizontally.  To activate the debug menu in Expo, the device needs to be shaken vertically.  BlueStacks only implementing horizontal shake was a poor decision.

A work-around for any device with adb debug attached is:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported yet. Just tilt with left-down and left-right keys.
This was from 3 months ago:
https://getsatisfaction.com/bstk/topics/shake_shake_shake_feature

Comment: tanx - but what's your mean?

Comment: From what I've read on their forums, you can only simulate Tilt with BlueStacks, not the shaking feature. This will be implemented in future versions.

Comment: It is fully supported, in BlueStacks 2. There is a button that "shakes" the window and send the intent action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use genymotion, its better than bluestacks. It also supports Shake feature for WeChat.

Comment: right - but genymotion not support all of android apps.too, are in genymotion "free for personal use' version "Shake" Available?

Comment: no emulator can support all apps. Yes its available in free version.

Comment: but from where? - can you help me? - i can't see Shake in genymotion menu.

Comment: There is an option of Rotate Screen `(Ctrl+F11)`. I have used this only in WeChat. Image [Link](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=714008555056)

Comment: i thought that just make Rotate - your point is Rotation ? - the Rotation make Shake too!?

Comment: i thought that just make Rotate - your point is Rotation ? - the Rotation make Shake too!?

Comment: Yes it also acts as Shaking of your device.

Comment: tax - too , you can help me in this post? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720624/multiple-file-download-manager-in-listview-progress-pause-resume-android

Answer (score 0):

I would simply record the sensor readings from a real device shake and then make a library that dispatches a fake shake whenever I need one:

[How can I unit test an Android Activity that acts on Accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806976/how-can-i-unit-test-an-android-activity-that-acts-on-accelerometer/2807245#2807245)